# Why doesn't the golang crypto example use a random IV?

Tags: encryption, go, initialization-vector

According to CWE-329 NON-Random IV's allow for the possibility of a dictionary attack. 
However, [in the AES crypto example](http://golang.org/src/crypto/cipher/example_test.go), golang docs use a non-random IV:

```
ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
```

Is this implementation safe or should I use a random function to get my IV?

Comment: You're mistaken. In the encrypt case it's using a random IV. In the decrypt case it's using the IV from the message. Don't let the fact that the IV is initialized as a slice of the ciphertext fool you; the next thing it does is read random bytes into that slice from a [strong random source](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#pkg-variables).

Comment: Thanks for clarification about the GO exemple , which indeed randomize the IV by doing a  `io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv)`. I think that it is a bit misleading. Doing a `iv := make([]byte, [:aes.BlockSize])` assignment would be clearer.

Comment: that's not even valid syntax.

Comment: I was completely wrong. Please read my answer again. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is secure, because the IV is filled from a Cryptographically Secure Pseudo Random Number Generator (CSPRNG) which is `/dev/urandom` by default and provided from the OS. From the `ExampleNewCBCEncrypter` function:

```
iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Your very first sentence is wrong. `make` always returns a zeroed slice. `ciphertext` will always be all zeroes in the OP's example.

Comment: 100% of this is wrong. If the capacity isn't provided when making a slice, it's the same as the length. Whether or not it's provided has nothing to do with whether the backing array is initialized; it's always initialized to zeroes.

Comment: You can't access uninitialized memory in Go without using "unsafe".

Comment: Even if you were to use initialized memory for an IV, it is most certainly *not* sufficient. The chances of having non unique blocks of 16 bytes from your heap on subsequent runs is relatively high.

Comment: @ArtjomB. this is still wrong because the example *does* init the IV from `rand.Reader` exactly the way you're recommending (line 77 :)

Comment: @ArtjomB.: you can do pretty much anything through "unsafe": http://play.golang.org/p/ncLFq2zsmx (and indirectly through cgo). There's no chance of accessing unsafe through the aes code, since it's not imported at all.